# Texmaker uses 100% of a core indefinitely after the compile is complete

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

I'm using TexMaker on ubuntu 18.04 to write my PhD thesis. As of today I've noticed that when I compile my document, one of my CPU cores remains at 100% utilisation, even after the compilation has finished, until I close down TexMaker. I'm not sure if it did this before today, but it is from today that I've noticed it.

This doesn't seem right, any thoughts on what this might be caused by, or what I might be able to do to stop this? I have a Ryzen 3600 (6core, 12 thread), and 32GB 3200MHz RAM, so it's not really an issue, but it does cause the fans to start up, which is slightly annoying.

Cheers

Comment: Does the problem persist with a minimal document? If not, try to narrow down the problem by deleting lines from the document while it still persist, make a minimal example and post here.

Comment: you should be able to use top or ps or similar to see what process is running, is it texmaker itself or is it a process it has forked such as the pdf viewer or whatever?

Comment: It's really strange, I've gone to recreate the issue this morning and check with ```top``` but now it's not doing it. I'll be doing more editting today so if the problem returns I shall update this comment thread.

Comment: Little update to this, I think I've recreated the issue. I was typing out a long equation in the equation environment, and I've written out a long line that would have usually just resulted in a bad box warning, but instead it is unable to generate the PDF. If I remove some of the equation to make it shorted, it then gives two ```! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK```... warnings when trying to compile, but then will compile on the next try, but still carries on to use a full core. It says pdflatex in top, and this has risen to 3 full cores used whilst just typing out this comment.